# Python Selenium UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I always write and run my program in PyCharm, But when I open it in regular python it gives me this error.. (It works in pycharm)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random

print("\n")
user_input = input("Username: ")

##########################################################
path = r"C:\Users\John\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
##########################################################

text_file = open(user_input +  str(random.random()) + ".txt", "w")
text_file.write("GoogleSearch:\n\n")
##########################################################
print("Google results:\n")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/#q=" + user_input)
for n in range(20):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="pnnext"]/span[2]""").click()
    except: print("out of pages")
    pass
    time.sleep(2)
    posts2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_Rm")
    for post2 in posts2:
        print(post2.text)
        text_file.write(post2.text + "\n\n")


print("\n")
print("Pipl results:\n\n")
text_file.write("\n\n")
text_file.write("Pipl results:\n\n")
driver.get("https://pipl.com/search/?q=" + user_input + "&l=&sloc=&in=5")
posts1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("line1")
for post1 in posts1:
    print(post1.text)
    text_file.write(post1.text + "\n")

time.sleep(1)
driver.close()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\peopleSearchTool.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(post2.text)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u203a' in position 23: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Please correct the title.

Comment: @kame well, I have fixed it by DOWNgrading too python 2.7, however i'm having a new problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972965/python2-7-seleuim-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the root of the problem is a codepage. 
PyCharm runs your program in a console with a Unicode codepage, while a standalone run apparently works in a console with a codepage 437 (which exists from 1980s). 
Unicode codepage contains a character with a code #203a, but codepage 437 does not, since it contains only 256 characters.

So, in order to print a string with characters with codes above FF you have to encode/decode your string or change your console codepage.
However, take attention that both methods could impose a lot of problems.

The better option is just to stick to Unicode and never print to non-Unicode consoles.

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean, I'm fairly new to python. could you explain a little more?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html