# Python2.7 selenium errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, text

So I recently transfered too python 2.7 from python 3.5 due to not being able to use py2exe, But I had this script running on 3.5 but now I get an error in 2.7 if you guys could give me a hand and help me reslove this issue, it'd be great.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import random



print("\n")
user_input = raw_input("Username: ")


##########################################################
path = r"C:\Users\Skid\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
##########################################################



##########################################################

text_file = open(user_input+ str(random.random()) + ".txt", "w")
text_file.write("GoogleSearch:\n\n")
print("Google results:\n")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/#q=" + user_input)
for n in range(10):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pnnext']/span[2]").click()
    except: 
        pass
    time.sleep(5)
    posts2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_Rm")
    for post2 in posts2:
        print(post2.text)
        text_file.write(post2.text + "\n")



print("\n")
print("Pipl results:\n\n")
text_file.write("\n\n")
text_file.write("Pipl results:\n\n")
driver.get("https://pipl.com/search/?q=" + user_input + "&l=&sloc=&in=5")
posts1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("line1")
for post1 in posts1:
    print(post1.text)
    text_file.write(post1.text + "\n")

time.sleep(1)
driver.close()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Skid/PycharmProjects/untitled/2nd.py", line 34, in <module>
    text_file.write(post2.text + "\n")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u203a' in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting these lines after `print(post2.text)`

```
A=post2.text

A=A.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

And instead of `text_file.write(post2.text + "\n")`
write `text_file.write(A + "\n")`

It worked for me.

to debug next button issue try the following code:

```
for n in range(10):
nextbutton = 0
try:
    nextbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pnnext']/span[2]")
    if nextbutton !=0 :
        nextbutton.click()
except: pass
time.sleep(5)
if nextbutton != 0 or n==0:
    posts2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_Rm")
    for post2 in posts2:
        print(post2.text)
        A=post2.text
        A=A.encode('ascii','ignore')
        text_file.write(A + "\n")
```

Comment: Like this?         print(post2.text)
        text_file.write(post2.text + "\n")
A=post2.text
A=A.encode('ascii','ignore')
 I did that, But it didn't work hmm

Comment: Damn, thanks, weird how that works.. Any idea how to get it too stop if there is no more button to click?

Comment: what do you mean by "no more button to click" ?

Comment: Like, what if you search something so spefic on google, there's only 4 next buttons to click, because I have that problem. There's only 4 pages and at the last page it just loops

Comment: Skid I have added the code to solve the next button issue checkout

Comment: Damn, That looks good, But it scrapes first page and then goes to Pipil. I have some questions if you don't mind; When scraping google some of the "_Rm" class's are like this, "stack code › questions › Skid" any idea how to scrape the hyperlink and get the URL from it?
Another question, When I try to run py2exe I get my first problem. One

Comment: to stop scraping only first page,in the last line of the code use "continue" instead of "break" in the "if" condition

Comment: Where will the text file be saved?

Comment: Ah It worked, thanks!, What do you mean where would it be saved?